# Sending message without input elements

Tags: php, post, input

I want to send a feedback message from one page to another without using input elements via POST method. Is that possible? Or is there other way around?

What i want is applying a value from one page to another page's variable.

i.e.: Sending "Yaba Daba Doo" string from 1.php to 2.php's variable, named $info.

1.php:

```
<?php
$info = "Yaba Daba Doo";
?>
```

2.php

```
<?php
$variable=$_POST['info'];
echo "The message is:".variable;
?>
```

How can i pass info variable to 2.php using POST method, without input elements?

Comment: you can store the feedback message in a [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: You need to improve your question. Desperately. At the moment it's impossible to tell what you need and why.

Comment: What do you mean by sending message. Do you want to send some variable value to another page?

Comment: @gcx: If you did not respond in next some minutes people are going to close your question.

Comment: It sounds like you want sessions. But it is still not 100% clear. Where is `"Yaba Daba Doo"` coming from? Is it user input? Are you processing a form in one page and you want to "send" this data to another page after processing?

Comment: still it's unclear. Why so **abstract** and vague description? Why can't you tell REAL story? WHAT data and for what purpose being sent? Is it too hard to tell exact case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use session variable to store data on server and access across the pages of your application.

If you want a secure way to send this variable you can use session so that end user can not see it
An example

```
page1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['mes']=$info;

page2.php

session_start();
echo $_SESSION['mes'];
```

And the another way is to pass variable in GET which I will not recommend user can see the value of your input variable

Comment: @Felix: I understand that message means some variable value but I asked him what he actually wants

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: It's fine, sessions might be what he want, but if you use sessions, you are not sending data anywhere. The data is just stored at the server somehow and read by the processes... (one could argue that the session ID is sent though ;)).

Comment: @Felix: just wait for his response may be you are right or ME

Comment: @Felix: If you read the title of the question you will understanding what he is talking about. He want to pass the variables across the pages

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: No, it is not clearer. The title and the description are confusing. And I'm actually only talking about your description: *You can use session variable to send any data...*. The data is not sent, it is stored at the server. As I said, this might be the solution but your description is not good. The only data *sent* when using sessions is the session ID.

Comment: @Felix: True, And this is also true that data can be accessible across pages

Comment: @ShaktiSingh, @Felix: Yes I'm trying to pass variable. But all these arguments indicates that using SESSIONs is not the best way. Is there other way?

Comment: @Felix: At last conclusion is: You can store and access the data across application using session or using GET variable I know get is not secure and anyone can see your data. Do you have any other option to send data across application? Cookie can does but how much cookies you will use to send data. So finally session is the last hope and I Dont think there is any reason to keep downvote as well

Comment: @Felix: Alright i'll wait new messages and by that time i'll try SESSION. I'm not the one whose downvoting all messages btw. I appreciate every answer.

Comment: @gcx: Session is the right approach in this case, who said it is not the best way? It is *the only* way.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: (a) I didn't down vote your answer. In fact, it seems to be correct. (b) I think you misunderstood me. I say using sessions is the right approach but *your description of what sessions are doing is (was) wrong*. Sessions don't *send* data from one page to another, they *store* it on the server where it can be accessed by different processes. I see you fixed this now... (c) +1 from me for the correct answer.

Comment: @Felix: This is my weakness to give words I know what session for but due to my language I was unable to choose appropriate words. Thanks for your time and nice talk anyway. Thanks again

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: You're welcome, I hope I didn't sound too harsh because I didn't mean to :) I know it can be difficult to find the right words (I'm not a native English speaker)... Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a session to store your data, then when ever you want to store is call upon the $_SESSION global.

Here is more info about sessions:
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)
[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp)
[Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make a post request to 2.php from 1.php